# WSO2 API Manager Add hal+json

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have newly added **messageFormatter** and **messageBuilder** similar to:

```
<messageFormatter contentType="application/hal+json" class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>

<messageBuilder contentType="application/hal+json" class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>
```

In this two files:

- [API-HOME]/repository/conf/axis/**axis2.xml**
- [API-HOME]/repository/conf/axis/**axis2_blocking_client.xml**

in API Manager version 3.0.0.

But in the APIM version 3.0.0 all changes in this files discards because any server configuration is: [API-HOME]/repository/conf/**deployment.toml**, reference: https://github.com/wso2/docs-apim/issues/498

What is the correct way of adding these lines ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

1) Open `repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml.j2`.

i) Add these under `<messageFormatters>`

```
{% for message_formatter in custom_message_formatters %}
    <messageFormatter contentType="{{message_formatter.content_type}}"
                      class="{{message_formatter.class}}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

ii) Add these under `<messageBuilders>`

```
{% for message_builder in custom_message_builders %}
    <messageBuilder contentType="{{message_builder.content_type}}"
                    class="{{message_builder.class}}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

2) Add this to `deployment.toml`

```
[[custom_message_builders]]
content_type = "application/hal+json"
class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"

[[custom_message_formatters]]
content_type = "application/hal+json"
class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"
```

Ref: https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/setup/message_builders_formatters/message-builders-and-formatters/#custom-message-formatter

Answer (score 1):

In API Manager 3.0.0, adding custom message builders, formatters cannot be done with the deployment.toml file.

Therefore, if you need to configure additional message builders, formatters, you need to edit the `<APIM_HOME>/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml.j2` 
and add the required message builder and formatter.